# Given the hypothesis "if x is odd or y is even". What are the cases?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-explanation

I want to prove an implication by discussing all the cases.
So if the hypothesis is "if x is odd or y is even", what are the cases?

I assume there are two cases:

1) x is odd and y is odd

2) x is even and y is even

But I'm wondering if there is a third case that "x is odd and y is even"?

I know "or" is used in the hypothesis, 
but in Mathematics, we say (A ∨ B) is true if either A or B is true.
And (A ∨ B) is also true if both A and B is true. 
In this case, if A is "x is odd" and B is "y is even", can I say "x is odd and y is even" is one of the cases?

But there is something more...

For example,
"For all integers x and y, if x is even and y is odd, then x+y is odd".
This statement is true. So its contrapositive "For all integers x and y, if x+y is even, then x is odd or y is even" is also true. However, in this case, the conclusion "x is odd or y is even" doesn't include the case "x is odd and y is even", otherwise the statement would be wrong.

This is what is confusing me.

Could anyone please help me to clarify this?

Comment: Yes the third case you mention is possible. Mathematics almost always uses inclusive or.

Comment: I just edited my question and added an example. Could you please look at it?

Comment: In your new example, there is nothing inconsistent. Yes "x+y is even" implies that "x is odd or y is even," but it also implies an even stronger conclusion.

Comment: You are incorrectly treating the contrapositive as an "if and only if" type statement.

Comment: I finally understood what the difference is. Thank you very much!

Comment: While this third case is certainly possible, the question is how to prove such a conditional statement. To prove a statement such as $A\text{ or }B \implies C$ it would suffice to prove that $A \implies C$ and $B \implies C$ since the case where $A$ and $B$ are true is contained in both cases. See Dan Christensen's answer.

Answer (score 2):

> If the hypothesis is "if x is odd or y is even", what are the cases?

You want to prove: If x is odd or y is even, then P(x,y) is true.

If you want to prove this by cases, your hypothesis gives you two cases to consider: (1) x is odd, (2) y is even. For each of these cases, however, there may be other cases sub-cases, sub-sub-cases, etc. to consider.

**Sample Outline of a Proof by Cases**

Suppose: x is odd or y is even (your hypothesis).

---

**Case 1:** Suppose x is odd.

(You might now consider two sub-cases, say: (1.1) y is odd, (1.2) y is even.)

**Sub-case 1.1 :** Assume y is odd.

Prove: P(x,y) is true.

**Sub-case 1.2:** Assume y is even.

Prove: P(x,y) is true.

**Conclude:** If x is odd, then P(x,y) is true.

---

**Case 2:** Suppose y is even.

(You might now consider two sub-cases, say: (2.1) x is odd, (2.2) x is even.)

**Sub-case 2.1:** Assume x is odd.

Prove: P(x,y) is true.

**Sub-case 2.2:** Assume x is even.

Prove: P(x,y) is true.

**Conclude:** If y is even, then P(x,y) is true.

---

(In both cases, we have proven that P(x,y) is true.)

**As required:** If x is odd or y is even, then P(x,y) is true.